# Eclipse Android Phonegap App Emluator only displays "Hello World" instead of own index.html

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build

I´ve just started a phonegap project in eclipse and set up everything.
I inserted my index.html (with images and stuff) into the "www" folder and started the emulator, but instead of showing my index.html file it just shows the "hello world" example app.

Why isn´t the real index.html document showing in the emulator?

thanks !

Comment: In your res/xml/config.xml, are you pointing on the right index.html ? <content src="/index.html" />

Comment: in res/xml/config.xml it´s:  <content src="index.html" /> in MainActivity it´s super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); and the index.html is in the www folder

Comment: don´t know what the problem was, finally just set it up again and it worked..

Answer (score 0):

don´t know what the problem was, finally just set it up again and it worked